# How to convert nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, converters

I need to get data according to `nvarchar` column that holds numbers, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '362X' to data type int.

I tried this:

```
select modelcode 
from model 
where cast(modelcode as int )> 10000 - ERROR
where cast(modelcode as bigint )> 10000 - ERROR
where pws_modelcode+0 > 10000 - ERROR
order by ModelCode asc
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Maybe because your value 362X isnt an int value, it has letter in it? If you want that as an INT you need to replace X first.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @SqlKindaGuy I have no x in this column...

Comment: The error says otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`:

```
where try_cast(modelcode as int) > 10000
```

In other databases, you can use a `case` perhaps with regular expressions:

```
where (case when modelcode ~ '^[0-9]+$' then cast(modelcode as int) end) > 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all non numeric characters except minus sign with null and then convert to INT.

```
select  modelcode from model where  cast(REGEXP_REPLACE(modelcode,'^0-9-','') as int )> 10000
```